# MySQL variable precedence

Tags: mysql, sql

In one of my MySQL table column fields may have `NULL`, `0`, empty or space character value, also 1, 2, 45, etc..

I need just easier way for filtering positive integer values against empty ones.

I know I can use simply `field <= 0` when I need empty values but `null` values are excluded, simply I'd add `or field IS NULL` this does make sense.

But is there a way to accomplish this with one statement?

Comment: what you have tried so far? Show some code here

Comment: I've already included what I've tried. So please give up such a template comments, really sucks. Just read carefully... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM tablename
  WHERE IFNULL(colname, 0) <=0;
```